# Keep model data sorted?

Tags: sorting, ember.js, ember-data

My Ember data is database-based, but Ember maintains its own copy.  So while the CRUD calls return sorted data always, it gets out-of-sort in Ember when data is added.  The obvious fix is to have Ember stay in sync with the database, but that seems to violate the premise of Ember, plus there's no obvious "reloadAll" call.

But there's also no obvious "sortBy" that applies from a model.  I did try adding a...

```
phrasesSorted: Ember.computed.sort('phrases', 'phrase')
```

to my phrases model, but couldn't figure out how to get it referenced from the component (e.g. {{#each model.phrasesSorted as |phrase|}} doesn't do it.)

What's the Embery-way to easily present data sorted?  Is this a case where I need to write a bunch more code - e.g. custom routes and controllers - to do something that seems simple, or just me missing the simple?

Answer (score 0):

You use `computed.sort` in wrong way. Please use:

```
phrasesSorted: Ember.computed.sort('phrases', 'phrasesSorting'),
phrasesSorting: ['phrase']
```

Then referencing it via `model.phrasesSorted` would just work - no matter if inside controller, template, route, component or service.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Apparently I was using that incorrectly, but I'm also using this incorrectly, as I'm getting no results.   I've tried that in an component and in the model; not getting data back.  So to the basics... why do I need both lines?  What is the second line doing?  And which type of module - model, component, etc. - should this be in?  Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is phrases? If phrases is a plain array, change it to be an array of objects instead, such as `[{text: 'b'}, {text: 'c'}, {text: 'a'}]`. If it's a collection of child records, then it's fine. Your computed sort should just include the attribute of the phrase model, like `phrasesSorting: ['text']`

Comment: It's a model.  Four elements, including "Phrase", which is the sort-target.